# A question about the distinct zeros of some specific polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i ^ {\alpha_i}$ be the decomposition of the natural number $n$ in prime factors. 
Let $\omega(n) = r$ and $\Omega(n) = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i$
Define

$ n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^r(x-p_i)^{\alpha_i}$

Using the Mason-Stothers theorem one can show that:

$ \Omega(n) - \omega(n) +1 \le n_0 $
where $n_0 := deg(rad(n(x)+1))$ is the number of distinct zeros of $n(x)+1$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
I am concerned with finding out for which numbers $n$ equality holds:
$ \Omega(n) - \omega(n) +1 = n_0 $

So far I could prove, that if the equality above holds then:

1. Case: $\Omega(n) = n_0$

This means that $n= p^{n_0}$ is a prime power

2. Case: $\Omega(n) > n_0, n_0 = 1$

Then we have:
$n= p(p+2)$, $(p,p+2)$ are twin primes, $n(x)+1 = (x-(p+1))^2$

3. Case: $\Omega(n) > n_0, n_0 > 1, \omega(n) \le 2$

In this case $n = p^{\alpha}(p+2)^{\alpha}$, $(p,p+2)$ are twin primes, $\alpha \ge 3, \alpha = 1 \text{ mod } 2$ and $n(x)+1 = g(x)(x-(p+1))^2$ for some separable polynomial $g(x)$.

4. Case:$\Omega(n)>n_0, n_0 > 1, \omega(n)>2$

Is it true, that this case (4.) can never happen? If so, how to prove it. If someone has an idea I would be very happy.